# Typescript Function Arguement with Child/Inherited class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to write a function that sets some properties on its arguments (not return a new object), the argument is of a class that extends from the same basecalss ie

```
class BaseEvent {
    string eventName!;
}

class DeleteEvent extends BaseEvent {
    string deleteReason;
}

class UpdateEvent extends BaseEvent {
    string updatedBy;
}

const modifyEvent = async ( event: BaseEvent){
switch event.eventName{
case "deleteEvent":
event.deleteReason="xyz"; //doesn't work deleteReason doesn't exist on base class
return;

case "updateEvent":
event.updatedBy="abc";
return;
}
}
```

and so I tried this:

```
switch (true){
case event instanceOf DeleteEvent:
event.deleteReason="xyz"; //doesn't work deleteReason doesn't exist on base class
return;

case event instanceOf UpdateEvent: //still doesn't work
event.updatedBy="abc";
return;
}
```

I've also tried typecasting

```
let modifiedEvent= event; //argument event
switch event.eventName{
case "updatedEvent":
modifiedEvent=<UpdatedEvent> modifiedEvent; //no luck here either
}
```

Now there should be a simple/clean solution for this but sadly my patience is exhausting. Any suggestion would be very helpful. Again I want to take an object of child class, see if its of childA or childB and if its childA then i update one property and if its childB then i update another property and these properties don't exist on both child types

EDIT: Also the function is async because based on what child class this is I'm doing some database read operations etc

Comment: This doesn't quite look like TypeScript... Are you sure you are posting on the right section? If so, please post an example in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play).

Comment: Why not move that logic into the class, like into some form of handler function? That is one thing subclasses are good for.

Comment: Hey. This is typescript, if i have screwed up with syntax then my apologies but you get the idea.. its more like psuedo case but ive tried sticking close to syntax @elclanrs

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm provided with a library internally used that contains all these classes, so if youre talking about that code then I'm out of luck.. also theres already a helper function thats to call this function (populateEventDTO) the populateEventDTO should take events of any subclass types and update them from DB accordingly

Comment: If the code was correct the example would work. Fix the code to be typescript and then if you still encounter the problem we can help you.